When deleting attribute from GDB file all the fields in the remaining attributes get deleted as well in QGIS
In QGIS 3.38.2 I have a gdb shapefile with many attributes, let's say A100, A200, A300 and with many fields. When I go to the edit through the "Open attribute table" and delete A200, all the fields in A100 and A300 disappear upon saving the changes.
Is this a bug, or what I am trying to perform is not possible for a gdb file?
The process that I described is what I usually perform for a shp file. A workaround is to save the gdb file and uncheck the attribute from the saving dialog box.

Feels like a bug. Could you provide a small dataset as test data?

I could provide a dataset but I don't have enough privilege to attach a file.

Use the link :  https://we.tl/t-UcXLnrBDBc         Open the table editor and delete the column Entity_Name   Then save the changes and you might see many of the data on the next 7 columns will be set to null, basically rendering the file useless.

Thanks @Francis. May I attach the data you provided in the previous comment to the issue report created by you on github?

Note there is no such thing as a GDB shapefile. A GDB is a specific format and a shapefile is another.

I can confirm that it is a QGIS issue.
Anyway, the data is not corrupted. You just need to click on the "Reload the table" icon  in the Attribute table to make the field values appear again.
Please report the issue to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues otherwise the issue cannot be fixed.

It works.  For other readers the "reload icon" is the icon with 2 blue arrows located top left (4th icon).  I will report to qgis.
